# AngularJS E2E/functional test controller

Tags: angularjs, testing

I just start with tests in AngularJS. Please help me to fix it.
My cript

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'svc', function ($scope, svc) {
  $scope.data = [];
  svc.query()
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}]);
```

and test spec

```
describe('ctrl', function () {
  var ctrl, scope, svc, def, data = [{name: 'test'}];
  beforeEach(module('test'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
    svc = {
      query: function () {
        def = $q.defer();   
        return def.promise;
      }
    };
    var a=jasmine.createSpy(svc, 'query');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('ctrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      svc: svc
    });
  }));
  it('should assign data to scope', function () {      
    def.resolve(data);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(svc.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.data).toBe(data);
  });
});
```

It fail:Error: Expected a spy, but got Function. in http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js (line 2125). Can you help me

Comment: Its E2E testing what you do, not unitTesting...

Comment: @lin No it is unit test with jasmin.

Comment: @lin no, not at all.

Comment: Sure it is, you made a functional test and `$scope` is binding data to `ng-view`. Its a core behavior. Its can't be a unit Test so. Testing Data like `expect(scope.data).toBe(data);` isn't a unitTest at all. Its a functional test, while using `$scope` its a E2E test, nothing else.

Comment: Please explain me why this is a unitTest while no unitTest rules/hints can be found in that test. (Testing query, Testing Data....)

Comment: @lin you can use your own definition of a unit test and of an e2e test, but don't think your definition is the accepted one. An e2e angular test typically uses protractor, and simulates an end user using his browser to use the application as a whole (views, controllers, services, routing, and back-end). That's why they're called **end-to-end** tests. A unit test tests a single unit of code. In that case, the ctrl function. It is a unit test. And $scope has nothing to do with ng-view. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because its failing on expect method. expect method is expecting a spy to be passed in but its not. To fix this problem do:

```
spyOn(svc, 'query').andCallThrough();
```

Comment: JB Nizet answer is complete, follow his guidelines, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a spy using `createSpy()`, which returns a function you can spy on, but you nere use it. You're making your life more complex than it should be. Just let angular inject the real service, and spy on its `query()` function. Also, use $q.when() to create a resolved promise.

```
describe('ctrl', function () {
  var scope, svc;
  var data = [{name: 'test'}];

  beforeEach(module('test'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q, _svc_) {
    svc = _svc_;
    spyOn(svc, 'query').andReturn($q.when(data));

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('ctrl', {
      $scope: scope,
    });
  }));

  it('should assign data to scope', function () {      
    scope.$digest();
    expect(svc.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.data).toBe(data);
  });
});
```